# Pdf file viewing facing an issue in android

Tags: android, file, pdf

Hi in the pdf code I have a button view pdf .When click on pdf I am accessing the file as string url and then want to open the pdf file.But when I am try to click on the button I am having below issue .From external directory

Can any one help me reslove this issue.

pdf:

```
holder.pdf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    opportunity.getPdf_link());
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Uri pdf = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, mContext.getPackageName() + ".provider", file);

            Intent pdfOpenintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            pdfOpenintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            pdfOpenintent.setDataAndType(pdf, "application/pdf");

            try {
                mContext.startActivity(pdfOpenintent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                // handle no application here....
            }
        }

    });
```

In manifest:

```
 <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>

 android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/https%3A/www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
        at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1978)
        at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2371)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10247)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10201)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1667)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4586)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4544)
```

Comment: Your stack trace does not match your code. Your stack trace is showing a call to `startActivityForResult()`, while your code shows a call to `startActivity()`.

Comment: Can you explain me I am not understanding...

Comment: @CommonsWare this file could not be accessed.Check the location or the network and try again this issue I am facing now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileProvider need to grand access to folders from targetSdkVersion >= 24 .Create an xml file in @res/xml folder  provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

And Add this to manifest

```
  <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

change

```
 Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
```

to

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",file);
```

and change

```
Intent pdfOpenintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        opportunity.getPdf_link());
               // Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                Uri pdf = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, mContext.getPackageName() + ".provider", file);


                pdfOpenintent.setDataAndType(pdf, "application/pdf");
                pdfOpenintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this helps.....

Comment: @res/layout folder

Comment: I am getting an error this file could not be accessed.Check the location or the network and try again

Comment: pdfOpenintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); this also same issue

Comment: Process: com.genworks.oppm, PID: 18800
    java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=19; index=20
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1999)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:748)

Comment: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=19; index=20
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1999)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:748)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:418) yes I am facing an issue

Comment: <external-cache-path name="images" path="." /> add this and see instead of <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>  yes I changed

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0 this error I am getting

Comment: open the file path and then coming back to window screen with no error

Comment: Make sure you have a pdf viewr n your device....... If accept answer if this has helped you thanks